# How to properly Set RadGridView.IsBusy while grouping

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, dispatcher, radgridview

In my scenario Telerik Rad gridview becomes unresponsible for a couple of seconds while grouping certain amount of data. All I want to do is to show some kind of loading indicator for this period of time. I tried to simple leverage OnGrouping, OnGrouped events to set IsBusy like this:

```
OnGrouping(){  gridView.IsBusy = true;}
OnGrouped(){  gridView.IsBusy = false;}
```

But it does not work. It looks like Telerik GridView performs all grouping in UI thread without any chance for 'IsBusy = true' being proceed before grouping finishes.

Anybody knows to to achieve that? 
Or more generally how to force layout update during 'OnGrouping' event?

Thanks in advance

Comment: OnGrouping is launched for gridView or collection?

Comment: That's rad gridView event

Comment: Well I have not come across telerik gridView but normally you can do grouping on CollectionViewSource which is not connected with UI. Show some code how you perform grouping.

Comment: I don't perform grouping manually but RadGridView encapsulates such logic. I only provide original data set (IQueryable), and all future groupings/sortings/etc in grid are handled by control itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon that you do not have any option. UIElement, like RadGridView, must be created on UI so the way out, by creating it in background thread and then assign it to UI thread, does not come into play. In ordinary grouping it is made on CollectionView so I guess it may be carried out simultaneously but as you said in your case UIelement is responsible for it.

Comment: Looks like there is no "build-in" option in Telerik, at least i didn't found it and Telerik forum support didn't suggest anything but only synchronous data sources. It is quite strange and it definitely limits Telerik grid view usage in production.

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting your RadGrid inside a RadAjaxPanel. Then hook up a RadAjaxLoadingPanel to display an animated loading gif or some text while the grid updates.

Demo: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/ajax/examples/loadingpanel/loadingimages/defaultcs.aspx

Doco: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajax-loadingpanel.html

Comment: My RadGridView is from WPF world, not from ASP.NET, unfortunately :)